# Rewrite URLs to not include file extensions

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here's a recurring problem. There are similar questions on SO about this, but nothing quite answers my question.

I've got a website and I want every page to be available at only one URL. It should work dynamically on all pages, not on a sinlge hard-coded filename.

1. `domain.tld/foo` should redirect to `domain.tld/foo/`
2. `domain.tld/foo.php` should redirect to `domain.tld/foo/`
3. `domain.tld/foo/` should give the user (but not redirect him to) `domain.tld/foo.php`

1 and 3 are not too hard, but I can't figure out 2 without introducing a circular reference and failing with too many redirects. How would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these three rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/[^?\s]+\.php[?\s]
RewriteRule (.+)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond $0 !.+\.php$
RewriteRule (.*[^/])$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule (.+)/$ $1.php [L]
```

And to exclude any other existing file, put this rule in front of the others:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule !.+\.php$ - [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this rewrites all URLs to `foo.php/`. They all point to the same location, which is good, but I want to get rid of the `.php`. I'm still tinkering with it.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting #1 is taken care of by

```
DirectorySlash on
```

which should be the default anyway.

For #2 and #3:

```
RewriteRule /(.+).php /$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule /(.+)/ /$1.php
```

Comment: The `DirectorySlash` is nice, thanks for that. The rest gives me infinite redirects for `foo/bar/` and `foo/bar.php`, while `foo/bar` leads to `foo`.

Comment: Hm, I thought from the question that you wanted this for single-component URLs.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding right, your problem is similar to what I had to face when I posted a question here [How can I detect if page was requested via a redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178405/how-can-i-detect-if-page-was-requested-via-a-redirect)

Although we couldn't find an answer entirely solving the issue, still some of the replies there may be helpful to you.