# How to identify if referrer is a 301 redirect

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I'm implementing a slug system for my website at the moment. I plan to redirect invalid slugs to the correct on that is stored in the database.
E.g.

> http://example.com/11/wrong-slug
>
> Hit db, check if 11's slug is wrong-slug if not do 301 redirect
>
> http://example.com/11/right-slug
>
> Detect 301 and inform user that they followed an invalid link

Is it possible to identify the 301 redirect preferably using PHP so I can ask the user to update there bookmark etc.

Thanks,
Jamie.

Comment: Why did you choose Gordon’s answer?

Comment: Check out my proposed solution at:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178405/how-can-i-detect-if-page-was-requested-via-a-redirect/18375175#18375175

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several solutions come to mind:

1. <s>You could try with [get_headers()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php)</s> *ah no, it dispatches a request to the URL, which is not what you want*
2. Since you are redirecting and testing for the redirect from the same machine anyway, you could simply write a message about the wrong slug into the user's session and display it the next time the view template is rendered. Many frameworks have a *flash messenger* component, that allow you do that easily, e.g. with Zend Framework you would use the following code in your controller action

   $flashMessenger = $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger');
   $flashMessenger->addMessage('We did something in the last request');
3. Instead of redirecting immediately when a wrong slug is found, you just render a View template that tells your user about the wrong slug and then use a meta or javascript redirect from the template. Optionally, you'd also write a plain link with the right slug to the template.
4. <s>And finally, you could also inject a custom header into the redirect via [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), which can then be read from your script.</s> *won't work either, because they will be lost once the browser got the redirect from the server*

Comment: So I could use get_headers(url) to return the status of the current page. However I don't see how I could use that to detect if they have allready been redirected. I figure I could add a flag to the redirected url. But again, that would lead to more problems.

Comment: I was wrong, get_headers() is not what you are looking for, but check the updated answer for other possible solutions.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively you could append a GET parameter to your url (if you don't mind that), and check for it in your PHP script. Something like:

```
http://example.com/11/right-slug?corrected-from=http://example.com/11/wrong-slug
```

On the same note you can use the session or cookies, but you must take care to remove them after detection.

Comment: You'll of course want to URL-encode that parameter, but this seems simpler than relying on what a particular browser might choose to send.

Comment: By adding the extra parameter the url again would change from http://example.com/11/right-slug so it would loop on itself.

I could use a session if(invalid){session();redirect}) might be time I learnt about sessions!

Comment: I'm not sure how you're choosing your redirects, but generally you would only look at the portion of the URI up to but not including the query string.

Comment: So your 301 destination location is rather */11/right-slug?corrected-from=…* than just */11/right-slug*? I don’t think that’s an option.

Comment: Becasue im using a slug system anything after /11/ is counted as a slug. Without enforcing a trailing slash and changing my mod_rewrite I cannot use any url parameters as users could end up bookmarking the corrected-from url.

Comment: I think that in the long run you'll really regret including parameters (and more particularly, parameter order) in your slug.

Answer (score 1):

A solution might be to check the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` in the "new" page : if it is set and corresponds to the "old" page, it's probably because your user has been redirected -- which means you might want to display your message.

But note that the [Referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer) is sent by the user's browser, and can be either disabled or forged -- so it's OK to use it to enhance the experience, but you must not rely on it for anything critical.

Comment: Just tried this method, a blank refferer is returned when visiting the redirected page.

Comment: Ho, too bad -- I did a quick test here, and it seemed to be working :-(

Comment: I did:
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.google.com");
then
javascript:alert(document.referrer);

How did you do this?

Comment: I used a RewriteRule in a .htaccess file -- but as you are using some PHP to do your redirection, you might as well use another solution than depending on the referer (for instance, use something based on a session variable)

Answer (score 0):

Found a working solution:

- Start session.
- Check session, if $_SESSION['INVALID_SLUG'] exists display message then unset session

  else
- Retreive slug from database e.g. /11/right-slug
- Get current URI e.g. /11/wrong-slug
- Compare, if different set $_SESSION['INVALID_SLUG'] and redirect to correct page

Any feedback?
I realise this will not detect a 301 redirect itself more detect a trigger assosiated with the redirect.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Keep in mind that sessions might not work (user has cookies turned off/blocked), the GET parameter solution is more reliable. If your page relies on sessions to work at all, this isn't a big deal.

Comment: It is impossible to detect a 301 redirect, because a redirect is nothing more than just telling the browser to do the same request to a different URL. The second request won't contain any information about any previous requests if you don't add it yourself (query parameter, session, cookie etc.).

Comment: That is what I suggested as solution #2 in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only useful option is to use a cookie.

When a URL with the wrong slug is requested, set a cookie for that URL without the slug:

```
$path = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, strrpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/')+1);
setcookie('wrong-slug', 1, 0, $path);
```

Then test if such a cookie exists and display your message:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['wrong-slug'])) {
    echo 'The location of this resource has changed. Please update your bookmarks.';
}
```