# How do you detect if the page is a redirect using Javascript in the client side

Tags: javascript, http-headers

Is there a way for me to find out if the current page is a 301 or 302 redirect from another URL? How do you get the previous URL of the page?

Comment: http header has a origin attribute

Comment: What is the use case? Maybe there's another solution.

Comment: @ChrisG Let's say I have a note-taking chrome extension app, I use the current URL as the key and attach notes to it as a way to determine the note is associated with this URL. Now, the site owner decides to upgrade his site and change the URL completely, and redirects all users to this new URL pattern. How do I retrieve my notes for both the new and old URL?

Comment: A redirect only happens if the user first navigates to the original URL. Maybe you can catch that via `chrome.webNavigation.onCommited`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no, you cannot tell the type of redirect.

You can look at the Referer header in JavaScript:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp

```
document.referrer
```

This will tell you what page the user was interacting with (generally) before they came to your page. It will not tell you if it was a redirect. You could make an AJAX HTTP request against that page to see if you get a 301 or 302 message back. But that won't 100% tell you if it was a redirect. If you are over HTTP and the referring page was HTTPS, then this header isn't set.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer

Comment: What if someone disabled referrer on his site? Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: putting the referrer in the HTTP headers is part of the browser specs, but as you note, a person can disable the referrer via various ways. Assuming the browser follows that request and doesn't send the referrer header, then there's nothing to be done to get it. As others mentioned, you can get the Origin, but that only tells you the server not the full URI.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP Header will have a Origin Attribute check there.

Comment: Origin only gives you the server, it won't give you the full path to the page that might have redirected you there.

Answer (score 0):

To get the url use document.referrer

As far as I know there's not a good way to detect a 301 or 302, especially via javascript. You could look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963328/how-to-identify-if-referrer-is-a-301-redirect) for ideas (but they use php). If you have knowledge of what urls the client will be coming from you can use the url taken from document.referrer to determine what action should be take.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the redirecting page, you can pass information by query string.

redirect.php

```
<?php
header('Location: target.html?referrer='.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], true, 301);
```

target.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>target of redirection</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const referrer = urlParams.get('referrer');
    console.warn('referrer >'+referrer+'<');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```